# how to create hash value from random bytes using secureRandom equivalent class in C# using SHA-512

Tags: java, c#, .net-core, hash, secure-random

Equivalent code for this Java code in C#

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte randBytes[] = new byte[64];
random.nextBytes(randBytes);
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
md.update(randBytes);
byte[] hash = md.digest();
byte[] encodedHash = Base64.encodeBase64(hash);
```

Comment: What is the ask here?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras The code is in Java and he is asking for a conversion to C#

Comment: Again, what is the question here? What is the *actual problem*? A message digest is more than a hash. SO isn't a code conversion site anyway. You can easily find the classes (and the docs) needed to generate random bytes, generate hashes, or BASE64-encode bytes to strings. If you want to sign a message, there are specific ways to do it that go beyond just calculating a hash. They include how to package the entire message, how to include the signature etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var randBytes = new byte[64];

using (var random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
{
    random.GetBytes(randBytes);
}

byte[] hash;

using (var md = SHA512.Create())
{
    hash = md.ComputeHash(randBytes);
}

string encodedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Unclear the use of calculating the hash of some random bytes.

Note that technically in Java `encodedHash` is in utf8 format. If you really want it in utf8:

```
byte[] encodedHash2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedHash);
```